# Passing arguments in Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, arguments

I am trying to specify 2 arguments with express JS start command, as specified below:

> npm start -x 5 -y 43

But in doing so, I can't pick the arguments with '-' and they are somehow skipped in the following code.

```
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
    log.info(index + ': ' + val);
    log.error("========="+array[index].toString());
});
```

Please help me to get the arguments with '-' as initials?

Note: I have tried using [Yarks](https://github.com/yargs/yargs), but its not working as specified in the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass arguments in npm script you must use double dash `--`:

```
npm start -- -x 5 -y 43
```

Check [npm-run-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) command documentation for more details.

Comment: It actually worked for the first '-x' but the it didn't worked for the second '-y'. I had to add one more '--' in front of the '-y'.
Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: What doesn't work for you? Remember that with this declartion: `-x 5 -y 43`, you'll get 5 arguments: `filename, x, 5, y, 43`, [node docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

Comment: `process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
    console.log(index +":"+ val);
});`

This is printing till '5' and **process.argv.length = 4**

Comment: The first argument is a process filename.

Comment: 0: /usr/local/bin/node
1: /Users/vinod/Desktop/bin/www
2: -x
3: 5

This is the output of console.log.

Comment: How is your `start` script looks?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },

Comment: You pass arguments from `npm start` not in **node process**, bun in **nodemon** process. This process **runs** node process and pass to it own arguments. To check that npm correctly pass arguments, use script which runs node process: `"scripts": { "start": "node app.js }`, for example.

Comment: Yes, I understood. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to pass in arguments with simply

```
npm start myArg1 myArg2
```

Both `bin/www` and `app.js` could access them.

Comment: The OP is looking for ways to mitigate the '-' in the arguments which the node doesn't seem to pick up while running.